# Синхронное выполнение IO операции в node.js

Tags: node.js, асинхронность, redis, замыкания

Я создаю приложение с использованием redis.

Следующий код:

```
let answer = redis_client.get('counter', (e, r) => {
    console.log(r);
}); 
console.log(answer);
```

Выведет сначала `answer`, потом `r`.

Как сделать так, что бы сначала выполнялась функция, переданная в функцию `redis_client.get` и только потом инструкции, написанные после get-запроса к базе данных redis?

Comment: Перенести `console.log(answer);` в колбек?

Comment: @Suvitruf что-то мне подсказывает, что это не совсем то, что нужно автору

Comment: @Suvitruf, дело в том, что после get-запроса не один `console.log`, а вся оставшаяся часть программы, => callback мне не подходит.

Comment: См. об этом: [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron) и [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).

Answer (score 0):

В node.js нельзя IO операции сделать синхронными в принципе. В этом суть.

В вашем случае вы можете попробовать использовать `async`/`await`:

```
const client = Promise.promisifyAll(redis_client);

async function doSOmething(){
    let r = await redis_client.getAsync('counter');
    console.log(r);

    console.log(answer);
    // много остального кода 
}
```